# Best practice to set default store : StoreManager or Emulation?

Tags: magento2, environment-emulation

Context : 
I'm coding a lot of CLI commands and I noticed most of the time if I don't set what store I'm operating on, it will counter-intuitively be set to the first non-global store. Since more often than not I need to operate on the global store (aka \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) I have begun setting the current store at the beginning of my scripts.

As far as I know there are two different ways to set the current store in Magento 2 : One is using the \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager and the other one is using \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation.

Question :
Which method is considered best practice for environment initialisation?

Thank you guys. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the method \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation is better.

--> this method is used when sending emails; it ensures the below are setup to clone the store preferences in 3 ways:

- theme
- store preference (config)
- locale used

Now, it is also common to only set the area code: with the object `\Magento\Framework\App\State $state` (`eg: $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);`)

this will give your script privileges to save entities that are restricted to be saved in backend for instance.